# Is it possible to generate a html5 cache manifest dynamically?

Tags: php, html, dynamic, cache-manifest

Is it possible to generate a html5 cache manifest dynamically? I've tried php (following this tutorial among others http://grinninggecko.com/dynamic-cache-manifest/ ) with no success at all.

Comment: Yes. Just make sure the format and response headers are correct. What specifically did you have issues with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870654/how-to-return-a-dynamic-cache-manifest-using-php-sym2

Comment: Please don't create multiple questions for the same issue; instead, update your original question with any new information.

Comment: ok sorry, just thought my first question was too narrow to get attention, and that train of thought seemed to work since at least you stopped by here on this new question with a broader title =p I'll try to be more modest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite sure, but let me tell you: getting HTML5 Offline content to work nicely with JavaScript applicationCache.update() et. al. is somewhat messy if you're new to it. In the end everything works as... documented! But CAVEAT LECTOR...

Anyway, here is a (hopefully) self-explaining PHP-only example, for which you'll need an `.htaccess` file. This will tell your server to interpret the `cache.manifest` as PHP code (needed since there is no `.php` extension).

Your `.htaccss` file in case you use a FCGI Wrapper:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest

<FilesMatch "\.(manifest)$">
  SetHandler fcgid-script
  FcgidWrapper /folder/to/your/php-fcgi-starter .manifest
  Options +ExecCGI
</FilesMatch>
```

Your `.htaccess` file in case you use the apache php module (most of the time, that will be the default case):

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest

<FilesMatch "\.(manifest)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Your `cache.manifest` file:

```
<?php

// only cache files in the following folders (avoids other stuff like "app/")
$folders = array('js', 'lib', 'views', 'styles');
$files = array('index.html');

// recursive function
function append_filelist(&$files, $folder) {
  if ($dh = opendir($folder)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if ( ! in_array($file, array('.', '..', '.svn')) &&
             (substr($file, -4) != ".swp")) {
        if (is_dir($folder."/".$file))
          append_filelist($files, $folder."/".$file);
        else
          //$files[] = $folder."/".$file."?hash=".md5_file($folder."/".$file);
          $files[] = $folder."/".$file;
      } // if
    } // while
  } // if
}

// init
foreach ($folders as $folder)
  if (is_dir($folder))
    append_filelist($files, $folder);

// generate output
$body = "CACHE MANIFEST\n\nCACHE:\n";
foreach ($files as $file)
  $body .= $file."\n";
$body .= "\nNETWORK:\n*\n";

// render output (the 'Content-length' header avoids the automatic creation of a 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' header)
header('Content-type: text/cache-manifest');
header('Content-length: '.strlen($body));
echo $body;
```

Good luck!